# Cant display data from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG8Jw.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title>ContactApp</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

        <h1>Contact app</h1>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                    <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Not so long time ago i started to learn MEAN stack and stuck in this problem.
As you can see on picture controller receive data from server but don't display it. What should I do to fix it? Thanks for any help. Sorry for poor English =D

controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    myApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        console.log("hi");

$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
    console.log ('RECIVED');
    $scope.contactlist = response;
});
}]);[enter image description here][1]
```

server code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app =express();

app.use (express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get ('/contactlist',function(req,res){
    console.log ('waitnig for my lovely request');

    person1 = {
        name: 'HBN1',
        email: 'HB1@robo.com',
        number: '(111) 111-1111'
    }
    person2 = {
        name: "HBN2",
        email: "HB2@robo.com",
        number: "(222) 222-2222"
    }
    person3 = {
        name: "HBN3",
        email: "HB3@robo.com",
        number: "(333) 333-3333"
    }

    var contactlist = [person1,person2,person3];
    res.json(contactlist);
})
app.listen(3000);
console.log ('server runing on port 3000');
```

Comment: do you see the data getting retrieved in console?

Comment: Yes, i can see it in get response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your rest api returns a json array.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.contactlist  =   [{
        name: 'HBN1',
        email: 'HB1@robo.com',
        number: '(111) 111-1111'
    },
    {
        name: "HBN2",
        email: "HB2@robo.com",
        number: "(222) 222-2222"
    }
    , {
        name: "HBN3",
        email: "HB3@robo.com",
        number: "(333) 333-3333"
    }];
 
   
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="container">

  <h1>Contact app</h1>

  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>E-mail</th>
     <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
     <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
     <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
     <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>

 </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You mean put data in controller? Yes, this way it works fine.

Comment: do you have team viewer?

Comment: one sec, ill install it

Comment: thats it. what now? Sor for waiting

Comment: id:304 758 365 pass:1sjq63

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment because my reputation is too low but what do you see if you console.log(response) in your controller?

if the data is coming through intact, it your page is likely loading before the data arrives, hence displaying as empty. If that is the case the following will work.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-show='isLoaded'>  // add this ng-show

    <h1>Contact app</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    console.log("hi");

 $scope.isLoaded = false   // add this

$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
    console.log ('RECIVED');
    $scope.contactlist = response.data; //make response.data as Daniel said above

    $scope.isLoaded = true;   // add this
});
}]);[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Still not works. In console log everything is ok.  do you saw image that i attach in top of post?

Comment: No i didnt! Maybe try res.send(contacts) instead of res.json(contacts) since you are sending an array of objects and not just json.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
    console.log ('RECIVED');
    $scope.contactlist = response;
});
```

To:

```
$http.get('/contactlist').then(function(response){
    console.log ('RECIVED');
    $scope.contactlist = response.data; // note the .data part
});
```

The `response` object properties can be found at : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http